# Сделать заглавные буквы маленькими

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строки:

```
International Conference on Advanced Materials with Hierarchical Structure
41
Сборник статей Международной научно-практической конференции
материалы всероссийской научно-технической конференции с международным участием
```

Как сделать все начальные буквы строк маленькими?
Желаемый результат:

```
international Conference on Advanced Materials with Hierarchical Structure
41
сборник статей Международной научно-практической конференции
материалы всероссийской научно-технической конференции с международным участием
```

Comment: Функция .lower() вам поможет.

Comment: @Эникейщик, если я не ошибаюсь, данная функция приведёт все буквы в нижний регистр, а мне нужно только первую

Comment: Она приведёт в нижний регистр те буквы, к которым вы ее примените.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = '''International Conference on Advanced Materials with Hierarchical Structure
41
Сборник статей Международной научно-практической конференции
материалы всероссийской научно-технической конференции с международным участием'''

for line in s.split('\n'):
    print(line[0].lower() + line[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = '''International Conference on Advanced Materials with Hierarchical Structure
41
Сборник статей Международной научно-практической конференции
материалы всероссийской научно-технической конференции с международным участием'''

def lower(obj):
    return obj.group(0).lower()

for s in text.split('\n'):
    print(re.sub(r'^[\w]', lower, s))
```